# Determinants and adjoints

Tags: linear-algebra

I just had a quick theory question. In my textbook, there's a formula:

$$det(adj(A))=(det(A))^{n-1} $$

It also states, that if I want to find, for example the determinant of adj(3A), I can do:

$$det(adj(3A))=(det(3A))^{n-1} $$

My question is, if I want to find the determinant of 3adj(A) instead, could I use the formula like this:

$$det(3adj(A))=(det(3A))^{n-1} $$

Or would it be:

$$det(3adj(A))=(3det(A))^{n-1} $$

Or are both wrong? In that case, how could I go about finding a formula to find the determinant of 3adj(A)? Thank you!

Comment: Remember the rule for determinants: we can remove a constant from the determinant (bring it outside the determinant), which divides all the entries of some row or column of the matrix. Over here, we are multiplying $3$ by the entire matrix, so one $3$ will have to be removed for each row in the matrix.

Comment: Yes, I understand if I have det(3A), to remove the constant I would have to multiply the determinant of A by 3 to the power of n, n being the dimension of the matrix. However, I wanted to know whether I could say that the determinant of 3adj(A) is equal to the determinant of 3A raised to the power of n-1, or not

Comment: Shouldn't it be $3^n$, since there are $n$ rows in $\operatorname{adj } A$?

Comment: @Bernard has provided the correct approach. In case you are wondering the first formula is a corollary of [Jacobi's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobisTheorem.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $\;\DeclareMathOperator\adj{adj}\adj(\lambda A)=\lambda^{n-1}\adj(A)$, hence
$$\det(\adj(\lambda A))=\det(\lambda^{n-1}\adj(A))=\lambda^{n(n-1)}\det(\adj(A)).$$